# if statement in my sql server 2008 select or my update query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can I have an IF statement in my select query or in an update query?

I want to set different values based on some substring values in my DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would use a CASE statement

```
select case Column when 'a' then 'bla' else 'not bla' end as SomeColumn
from SomeTable
```

Runnable example

```
select case xtype 
when 'p' then 'stored procedure' 
when 'd' then 'default'
when 'u' then 'table'
else 'something else' end as SomeType
 from sysobjects
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can

```
... SET field = CASE WHEN cond THEN val1 ELSE val2 END, ...
```

Comment: Can we return table result through  " Case " ?

Comment: @Niks: the result should be a valid expression

Comment: Actually I have condition which return either results and both query are different ( only for where clause  ) how to achieve that result ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression in order to make such evaluations as part of your `SELECT`.

Here is an example from MSDN:

```
SELECT   ProductNumber, Category =
      CASE ProductLine
         WHEN 'R' THEN 'Road'
         WHEN 'M' THEN 'Mountain'
         WHEN 'T' THEN 'Touring'
         WHEN 'S' THEN 'Other sale items'
         ELSE 'Not for sale'
      END,
   Name
FROM Production.Product
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [`case`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)